# How do I choose an ImageReader buffer type for my Android camera app?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have an app with a camera function. I'm using the Android Camera2 API. I've found that some Android devices (e.g. Nexus 6p, Nexus 5) work better if the `ImageReader` is configured to provide JPEGs:

```
imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(width, height, ImageFormatType.Jpeg, 2);
```

And some Android devices (e.g. Nexus 7 2013) work better if the `ImageReader` is configured to provide, say, `RGBA_8888`:

```
imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(width, height, (ImageFormatType)1 /* PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 */, 2);
```

The device that works better with JPEGs spits out this error if I use `RGBA_8888`:

```
[ImageReader_JNI] Producer output buffer format: 0x22, ImageReader configured format: 0x1
```

The device that works better with RGBA buffers spits out this warning if I use JPEGs: (It still works, but it's slow enough that the captured picture is dark.)

```
[ImageReader_JNI] ImageReader_lockedImageSetup: Receiving JPEG in HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 buffer.
```

I have to do some processing on what I get back, so ultimately it would be better if I could configure the camera to just spit out some sort of bitmap rather than a JPEG, since I have to convert the JPEG to a `Bitmap` before continuing.

How should I choose what buffer type to pass to the `ImageReader`?

Comment: What is your use case? Single snapshots (not many captures per second), or continuous capture (~30fps)?

Comment: I have a preview surface which takes continuous capture until you hit the take picture button, at which point it single-captures to the `ImageReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only guaranteed formats that all camera devices must support are YUV_420_888 and JPEG; even at that, LEGACY-level devices generally only support JPEG at maximum resolution (and YUV_420_888 at preview resolutions, not generally higher than 1080p).

You should be checking the list of supported formats in the device's [StreamConfigurationMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputFormats()) instead of just blindly trying some - while some devices may support random formats not listed in their official list, there's not much guarantee about how well they'll do so.

JPEG capture tends to be slower because LEGACY-level devices assume that when you want a JPEG, you want maximum still capture quality, which takes more post-processing than just a preview frame; plus, LEGACY devices may do flash metering and firing.  LIMITED or better devices allow you to control the post-processing quality, so it's not tied to the output format, and also generally support higher resolutions of YUV capture.

I'd generally stay away from RGBA if you want wide support - it working with LEGACY devices is a bit of a quirk, and LIMITED and better devices are unlikely to support it.

When you say that JPEG works, but is slow enough that the captured image is dark, I'm a bit confused - why does slowness mean a dark image? Or do you just mean the images come out dark?

Comment: On most of my devices, capturing to JPEG is fine. But on this one Nexus 7 2013, if I capture to YUV, the color is fine, but if I capture to JPEG, sometimes it's dark. I thought initially it was a case of stopping the repetition of preview frames or something, but that doesn't seem to be the case.